# One line of text not aligning with the whole paragraph?

Tags: css, properties, paragraph, center-align

Im a bit of a n00b -- but usually figure out a solution.

http://www.thisisclou.com/about

The last line in the first paragraph will not align with the whole text group ??

my CSS:

```
element.style {
letter-spacing: 1.4px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 55%;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
 }
```

directly on the paragraph ??

Any help would be nice.
:)
thanks
Sylvana

Comment: Sorry the re-direct !!
click 'Clou Studio Inc' in the bottom center to view the trobled page

Comment: That might be because you have two `a` tags in that `p` tag. The first `a` tag makes no sense.

Comment: The problem with these types of questions is that once someone answers and you fix the problem on that website, this question will not provide any use to future users.  You should show a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks so much TheBokiya !! that helps so much :0

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you have an `<a>` tag inside a `<p>` tag.